# Opening read-only OLEDB connection to MS Access back-end database while allowing updates via separate MS Access front-end

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, oledb

I have a back-end MS Access 2002-2003 database which stores blog entries. I created a separate front-end database with the forms for entering blog posts into the backend database. Finally, I have a website utilizing ASP to display the blog entries.

The website connects directly to the backend database using an OLEDB connection object. Whenever I open the form for creating a new post in MS Access, loading the blog post page on the website displays the error:

> Could not use "; file already in use.

I would like to be able to display the older blog posts even though the newest one is in the process of being added.

Answer (score 0):

Do all users have a minimum of read and write permissions on the directory in which the file resides? If not, the file will be locked because the .ldb cannot be updated.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the folder access rights it might be worth checking you are not opening the database up in exclusive mode as this would “lock out” other users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an OLEDB/ADO user, but I just Googled on this and [this page about ADO Recordsets](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_recordset.asp) indicates there's a static recordset type. It would seem to me that this would be exactly what you want, no?